# How to get rid of the key on top of keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am making a user registration page. I noticed that there is an auto generated key symbol on top the keyboard for all the `UITextField` except the first one. That key leads to the stored passwords secured by TouchID. It doesn't make much sense to have it for my "Re-enter email" text field. Is there a way to get rid of it? I just used a regular `UITextField` with either `.keyboardType` set to `.emailAddress` or `.isSecureTextEntry = true`.

However, if I jump straight from the first text field to the last, a plain keyboard is shown without the bar on top. Is this the expected behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure that you can remove the key only, what you could do in your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is to set the `autocorrectionType` for your keyboard.

Something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag == 0 {
            textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        } else {
            textField.autocorrectionType = .default
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

This will hide the suggestion bar when you´re on particular textfields. Set the tags for your password textfields and add these tags in the if-statement and you´ll hide the suggestion bar since you done need it there anyway,

Comment: The key bar still shows initially and only goes away after typing one character. I noticed this only happens to text fields that follow a `.emailAddress` text field. But it's good enough for me. Thanks!!

Comment: This happens because you have implemented `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and the code only applies when you enter a character. You could change it and use `func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { ... }` instead, this will notice when you have clicked the textField and you´ll have a better solution. Let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { ... }.  Is correct one

Comment: @iOS, indeed. Updated the post to clarify that more than just the comment

Comment: No I didn't do it in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, I just added `textField.autocorrectionType = .no` in `viewDidLoad()`. It makes more sense to me